# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook AND java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSF

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-poi

I'm using Apache poi 5.0.0 to read some data from an Excel(.xlsx) file. I started the project as a console appliacation so the implemetations work. I transfered the classes I use to a Servlet Project. Now the problem is, when I request 'generate' from my main page, I create a ReadXL instance. But when I try to instantiate the XSSF workbook I get the errors above. I have included all poi libraries (using IntelliJ) to the project (poi-ooxml-full, poi-ooxml too).

Requesting 'generate':

```
<form action="generate" method="get">
        <div id="list">
          <br>
          <!-- <div class="fileName">List</div> <div class="deleteFile"> X </div><br><br>
          <div class="fileName">List</div> <div class="deleteFile"> X </div><br><br>
          <div class="fileName">List</div> <div class="deleteFile"> X </div><br><br>
          <div class="fileName">List</div> <div class="deleteFile" onclick="alert('hi')"> X </div><br><br> -->
        </div><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="GENERATE .XLSX">
      </form>
```

Controller:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
        ReadXL newXL = new ReadXL("C:\\xampp\\tomcat\\webapps\\Public\\ΠΡΟΤΥΠΟ ΠΡΟΜΗΘΕΥΤΗ.xlsx");
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
```

ReadXL:

```
public ReadXL(String path) throws IOException{
        this.openXL(path);
        .
        .
        .
}

private void openXL(String path) throws IOException{
        xlFile = new File(path);
        fis = new FileInputStream(xlFile);

        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis); // get workbook <-- ERROR THROWN HERE
        .
        .
        .

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `poi-ooxml-5.0.0.jar` which contains that class.

Download from [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml/5.0.0/).

Comment: I have imported it in the library but reading other similar questions I'm not sure I did it the right way. The way I did it is by giong to the Project Structure in IntelliJ and added it in the Libraries

Comment: @tito Put all your jars in the tomcat/lib.